# How to remove dynamically created layout

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app i was created linear layout dynamically. That layout contains a text view and a button. Text view text was set using array list named as contact name. While clicking button i want to remove corresponding layout and remove element from array list at position'i'.

```
    final LinearL   ArrayList<String> contact_name = new ArrayList<String>();
    final LinearLayout lab_linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contact_list_layout);
    lab_linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        for (i = 0; i < Size_contact; i++) {
            final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
            layout.setId(i);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layoutParams.setMargins(5, 5, 0, 0);
            layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            Resources res = getResources(); 
            Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.searchbox); 

            layout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);

            final TextView Questions_value = new android.widget.TextView(
                    getApplicationContext());

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams_text = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layoutParams_text.setMargins(10, 5, 10, 2); 
            Questions_value.setLayoutParams(layoutParams_text);
            Questions_value.setText(contact_name.get(i));
            Questions_value.setTextSize(18);
            Questions_value.setId(i);

            layout.addView(Questions_value);

            final Button myButton = new Button(this);
            myButton.setId(i);
            myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.close);

            myButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(20, 20));
            layout.addView(myButton);

            lab_linear.addView(layout);

            myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int id = myButton.getId();

                     contact_name.remove(id);

                }
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you added new `Linearlayout` in `lab_linear`. if you want to remove it then use this method that remove all view  that are added it `lab_linear`.

```
if(lab_linear.getChildCount()>0)
    lab_linear.removeAllViews();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can make view to **disapper** by making it Gone like this

```
lab_linear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: want to remove linear layout layout only. Not lab_linear..while cliking button with id 'i', i want to remove linear layout layout with id 'i'

Answer (score 0):

if you use this method for remove items you should for any time remove delete all of views and again add all of them except of deleted one or Gone them but I offer you use listview instead of that